# How to convert network diagram in Visio format to a a networkx graph?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, visio

I have a network diagram that is sketched in `Visio`. I would like to use it as an input for the `networkx` graph from `node2vec` python package. The documentation says that there is a function called `to_networkx_graph()` that takes, as its input, the following types of data:

"any NetworkX graph dict-of-dicts dict-of-lists container (e.g. set, list, tuple) of edges iterator (e.g. itertools.chain) that produces edges generator of edges Pandas DataFrame (row per edge) numpy matrix numpy ndarray scipy sparse matrix pygraphviz agraph"

But, still, not mentioning other formats like Visio, pdf, odg, PowerPoint, etc.

So, how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create some data in the format referred to in the documentation, not just a network diagram. A Visio diagram will not do the job and I know of no way to do a conversion.